# MathJax script issue after customizing rstudio.markdownToHTML()

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio, mathjax, r-markdown

With knit2html() from the knitr package, I can generate html pages that contain latex equations and R code. But on my system equations are not rendered when using RStudio's "knit html" button.

It is because I have modified the way the "knit html" button works. To include a table of content on my html pages, I followed the Rstudio advice on [Customize Markdown Rendering](https://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/authoring/markdown_custom_rendering). And created an `.Rprofile` file at the root of the project directory that overrides default markdown rendering options. My `.Rprofile` only contains a function that replaces the `rstudio.markdownToHTML()` function as such:

```
options(rstudio.markdownToHTML = 
  function(inputFile, outputFile) {      
    require(markdown)
    htmlOptions <- markdownHTMLOptions(defaults=TRUE)
    htmlOptions <- c(htmlOptions, "toc")
    markdownToHTML(inputFile, outputFile, options = htmlOptions) 
  }
)
```

With this .Rprofile, I'm happy to have an automatic table of content generated on all my .RmD documents. **But equations are not rendered any more!** Equations appear as plain text.

- If I delete `.Rprofile`, reload R and click the "knit HTML" button in R Studio. Equations are rendered correctly but I don't have a table of content.
- If I run :

  `knit2html("file.Rmd", "file.html",
     options = c(markdownHTMLOptions(defaults=TRUE), "toc")))`

  Equations are rendered correctly and I have a table of content too.

Can you help me fix rstudio.markdownToHTML() so that it renders equations?

*Edit 03 April 2014*: Equations are visible if I open the html page in a web browser. They are not rendered in RStudio preview HTML pane. This might be an issue with the mathjax script not taken into account anymore by the Rstudio viewer?

Comment: It would be beneficial if you showed us what code you're currently using in your .Rprofile.

Comment: Can you post the output of `sessionInfo()`

Comment: Thanks Dason, all that's in my .Rprofile, is now copied above.

Comment: R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Ireland.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Ireland.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Ireland.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                     LC_TIME=English_Ireland.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] knitr_1.5.21 MASS_7.3-29 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] evaluate_0.5.1 formatR_0.10   stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.0.2

Comment: You could probably move your edit to an answer since it does sort of answer the question of how to make this work.

Comment: @Dason, thanks but it doesn't explain how to make it work in Rstudio.

Comment: But it's a workaround.  Honestly if it's not working in Rstudio and should be then file a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Dason suggested me to post this as an answer.

Equations are visible if I open the html page in a web browser.

Equations are not rendered in RStudio preview HTML pane. This might be an issue with the Rstudio viewer?