# What is the code behind the knit html button in rstudio 0.98.501?

Tags: r, rstudio

I followed the Rstudio advice to [Customize Markdown Rendering](https://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/authoring/markdown_custom_rendering). And created an .Rprofile file at the root of the project directory that overrides default markdown rendering options. But there seems to be [an issue with equation rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22454492/equations-not-displayed-after-customizing-markdown-rendering-in-rstudio) (see my earlier question).

What is the code behind the "knit html" button in RSTUDIO Version 0.98.501 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's running `rmarkdown::render('your_file.Rmd')`

by default it will create an output file with the same name as your `.Rmd` file and in the same directory.  If you checkout the documentation [1]  for the code, you'll see you can actually specify `output_file` and `output_dir` for different file names and different directory, respectively.

[1] http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmarkdown/